# how to focus on v-select programmatically?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, v-select, vuetifyjs3

I am using Nuxt3, how to set focus() on v-select programmatically?

Basically, OnSubmit  I want to validate the value. And if it is blank, I want to focus on the v-select programmatically.

Is it possible?
Is it possible in Nuxt3?
or at least, is is possible in Vue3?
Thank you.

Comment: You can add a `ref` to your `v-select` and then call `this.$refs.mySelectRef.focus()`. You should be aware that if the select is inside a dialog or menu or something else that uses animation - you may need to set the focus with `setTimeout`.

Comment: sorry but "this" is for nuxt2 right? keyword "this" is undefined when I tried it.
I am using nuxt3. but thank you for your idea.

Comment: I don't know **where** you are using `this` - its value depends on the position in the source code. That's why it is called `context`. If you are using the Composition API with `setup` - there is no `this` inside the `setup`.

Comment: ah thank you. yes, i am using it in side <script setup lang="ts"> 
is there any possible way to apply your code inside setup script? Sorry i am new to nuxt3 / vuejs. If only you could write it as an answer, i would pick it as an accepted answer.

Comment: There certainly is some way to do it in `setup` but I think it would be easier for you to do it outside. One of the Vue beauties is that you can freely mix Composition API with Options API. The Composition API (and the `setup` function) was invented to solve specific problems in large-scale applications. If you do not have such problems - you can continue using the Options API which is **much** simpler and understandable than the Composition API. You don't have to rush after the Composition API just because it is trendy/fancy/new fashion - only if you really can't do it without it.

Comment: ok, so what I need to learn is the keyword "Composition API" and "Options API". thank you, I think i am in the right direction now. I was mixing everything in Composition API, looks like that is the real problem. Let me learn about it first, well get back here later. thanks

Comment: Options API is the one that beginners must start with. It is supported in Vue 3. Composition API solves problems that you will rarely face with - and is noticeably more complex and confusing than the Options API, and the benefits are seen only in certain type of projects.